# disprove that $(L \setminus \{\epsilon\})^* = L^* \setminus \{\epsilon\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I need to disprove that for every formal language: 
$$(L \setminus \{\epsilon\})^* = L^* \setminus \{\epsilon\}$$
($\epsilon$ is the empty word).
I don't have an example to show that it isn't true, so can you provide me of an example that it is a false statement? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The language $(L \setminus \{\epsilon\})^*$ always contains the empty word, but the language $L^* \setminus \{\epsilon\}$ never contains it. Thus they are always different.